# Can I drop French accents when writing computer text in French?

Tags: diacritiques

I use the en-US keyboard, and as such, I lack access to *any* accents. I need to copy and paste letters with accents from Wikipedia every time I write French, which is very annoying.

Is it acceptable to just drop the accents when writing French in e.g. an (informal) email, a text, ...?

I understand French without any accents, but am not sure how others see it.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you use a Mac, you can use Option key combinations (e.g. option-e then e makes é), and if you use a Windows computer, you can use Alt key combinations (e.g. Alt + 1-3-0 on the number pad makes é)

Comment: Right, so _"I use the en-US keyboard, and as such, I don't have access to any accents."_ is an incorrect premise.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Thanks, but I use Arch :)

Comment: @MrLister I don't understand what you mean by that. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Doesn't Arch Linux have keyboard layouts? (To be honest, I tried experimenting with Arch Linux once, but then I gave up and went back to Debian.) Anyway, I hope these comments don't make the question off-topic.

Comment: @MrLister They do, but I don't know the exact key layout and yes, I can have a virtual keyboard or an image, but my screen measures only 15 inches diagonally, so that would be very annoying

Comment: @ I use both Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 distribution) and Windows (version 7, 8 and 10). With the workaround I suggest to my answer you can type french characters with a QWERTY keyboard very quickly and efficiently. For instance '+c gives ç, `+a gives à shift+6+o gives ô and so on. I do not know nevertheless anything about Arch...

Comment: On Linux I generally use a [compose key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Configuring_compose_key), with the additional benefit of being able to type other uncommon characters such as ç = `Compose,c,,`, Æ = `Compose,A,E`, ø = `Compose,/,o`, or even →= `Compose,-,>`. If you're using Gnome, there's an option for it in the advanced keyboard settings.

Comment: @F.X. Didn't know about this, thank you! Will definitely use it in the future! :)

Comment: Instead of copy-and-pasting every accent, I run my finished text through a spell-checker, which adds most of the necessary accents semi-automatically.

Comment: the grave accent can be typed like described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (all of a sudden I feel gifted for using a belgium azerty)

Comment: I work with EN-US layout all day for work purpose but for writing informal french i skip any form of accent. On formal i don't switch keyboard layout because i learned by alt-char when Pentium was the new gig in town. Knowing Alt+(130 to 151) by hearth is very easy. That's what people used to do in WordPerfect for Dos back in the days.

Comment: Cross-site related post: https://askubuntu.com/q/333227/579748

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It won't be correct French, but it is of course accepted in informal emails since the writer has a foreign keyboard. You are not expected to copy and paste letters. Some people add a P.S. explaining why they couldn't use accents when it's not obvious for the recipients (sometimes seen on internet forums), but you don't need to do it if the people you write to know you and know where you are.

If you had to write e.g. a Master thesis in French, now that would require you to use correct French, including accents. Then it would be best to invest in a French keyboard and save hours of tedious copy-paste.

Comment: While this answer's first part is correct, the recommendation isn't: You needn't buy an actual French keyboard and could instead just switch to a French layout and slowly learn that way: A physical keyboard may help you find where certain keys are, but it's not strictly necessary. Note, though, that the layout only works reliably on 105-key keyboards: [Most keyboards in the US have in fact 104 keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_keyboard) and so might be missing some mappings.

Comment: @errantlinguist When the OP says he "uses the en-US keyboard" I understand it meaning a physical US keyboard, with a small enter key and shift and Z next to each other. Otherwise the post wouldn't really make sense, if he's already using a European keyboard he could just switch the layout.

Comment: @errantlinguist "*the recommendation isn't [correct]: You needn't buy an actual French keyboard*" - My recommendation does not state that it is needed, even less that it is "*strictly necessary*". Surely your solution may work well for some people.

Comment: I have a [German keyboard with spanish stickers](https://keyshorts.com/products/portuguese-to-english-keyboard-sticker) in my work computer, which was a very inexpensive way to have both keyboards visible without extra hardware. I regularly write in 4 languages: Portuguese, Spanish, German and English. Whenever I want to change from German to spanish or portuguese (which I know without having to look), I just press Alt+Shift.

Comment: Every modern keyboard has a way to enter french (and other) accents. Don't change keyboards. Learn the way to enter accent. It could be ALT-130 for é, or something like [apple key]-e e for é. Once you get used to it, you'll be able to write them without even noticing.

Comment: Having to type 4 keys, one of them being hold while you type some random number the other three is hardly "not even noticing" to me. The compose key cuts that down to 3 keystrokes with no holding and intuitive keys (`'e` yields `é`, `/=` yields `≠` and so on). I bet there must be some windows software enabling this.

Comment: No, it is not accepted. Adding accents is possible with any keyboards, not doing it is lazyness. The easiest way is to use the US-intl layout with deadkeys. To write é, type `'e`. If you are not writing accents, you may as well write in sms language.

Comment: @JoaoBotelho Your comparison is invalid. German and Spanish use the same mechanical layout (called ISO in [this Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Physical_keyboard_layouts_comparison_ANSI_ISO_KS_ABNT_JIS.png)) while US (ANSI) and French (ISO) do not.

Comment: @AndreKR the need for the different keyboards doesn't refer to the mechanical layout but to the presence of the accent keys. Using the German keyboard it isn’t possible to type ñ, a significant accent in the spanish language (e.g. niño). The Spanish keyboard, on the other hand, is missing the ß, used in German (e.g. Suß). I write business emails and reports which require proper formal writting, and the easiest solution is to have stickers. Lookup the german and spanish layout for the “empty keys” from the Wikipedia link you gave - that’s the most important difference.

Answer (score 23):

With a QWERTY keyboard I would suggest the **[International Keyboard](https://www.csbsju.edu/Documents/MCL/resource/use-int-keyboard.pdf)**.
You can type very efficiently all the accents (not only for the French language; I use it, for instance, to type German diacritics as well).
It suffices to learn some shortcuts and voilà.
Everything is thoroughly explained in the following link:

http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/codeint/

For Ubuntu users see

https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu

For Mac users (thanks @Larme) see:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25643?locale=en_US

Regarding the second part of your question, may be I am a little bit purist, but I consider inacceptable writing French (even in textos) without diacritics.
In this way one will never master the French orthographe. French accents play a crucial role in the language and their absence may change completely the meaning of words (common examples: a/à, ou/où, du/dû and so on...).

Of course, this is my point of view. I am not a natif speaker but I know that many people (especially the younger ones) do avoid accents or use some astuces in order to decrease the time necessary for typing the message.

> cc ca va? Jspr ke tu va bi1

http://www.ikonet.com/fr/blogue/technologies/langage-texto-francais/

Français 2.0...

Comment: For Mac users: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25643?locale=en_US

Comment: Great answer. As a native speaker, I second the view that it is preferable not to drop accents when writing formal emails, as people tend to be quite tedious about the rules. Even in fora people are now more and more encouraged to write correctly. Also, when I see "ca va", I tend to read "ka va"...

Comment: @Paul-Benjamin That's interesting, as I'm also native, but I'd never read "ka va". :)

Comment: I thought the "..." made the irony clearer :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Oui, *cava* n'est pas terrible et il me semble plus souvent lire *sava* qui est meilleur phonétiquement parlant, ou simplement *cv* qui est plus court...

Comment: Anyone should be aware that shortening words like suggested at the end of this answer definitely yields a range of gut reactions, from approval to mild annoyance or even a feeling of offense. Definitely avoid in formal context and in case of doubt. Personally, I only use well-known abbreviation (like AFAIK) and only in highly specific context such as technical IRC chat. For details see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_SMS#Int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt_pour_le_langage_SMS_et_controverses

Comment: As a French person, I use the Canadian Multilingual Standard layout over the physical keyboard. There's a key combo for all French characters, including œ which seems to be missing from the International Keyboard (and, funnily enough from AZERTY keyboard too). It's not that useful with a spellchecker, but if you're like me, you'll like to be prepared in case you have to type a weird rogue character.

Comment: This! In Netherlands we use the US-International keyboard layout. ' + e = é. Just press the space bar if you want to write ' instead. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/781770/us-international-layout-does-not-appear-in-gnome/781840#781840

Comment: As a native and a quick reader, sometimes I need to read the sentence again because of a missing accent. Not using the accent on Ou/Où is one that annoys me the most. Also, using "sa" instead of "ça" makes my eyes bleed. It doesn't make you write faster and it has a completely different meaning (because sometimes native misuse it and take that excuse...) :)

Answer (score 10):

I recommend using a Compose key. It's built-in in Mac OS and Linux(usually activated somewhere in Settings→Keyboard) and there's a very good open-source Compose key for Windows called [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose).

How it works is that you press a key chosen by you as the Compose key(I like to use menu; between alt gr and ctrl) and then a sequence of characters to combine. Then Compose→e→'⇒é and such; a lot of different symbols can be produced this way.

Answer (score 5):

As a native French speaker and French teacher to foreigners, I would definitely recommend that you use the accents. 
If you don't, it is no longer French, even in an informal email or a text.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the personal experience, I've spent a lot of time on English keyboards not knowing the tricks to do accents under Linux and writing to French people or participating on French forums. All very informal contexts. I did get people complaining and pleading with me to get some accents already.

It can get wearing to read unaccented French, because a lot of common words are distinguished only by their accents - où/ou, à/a, conjugations of verbs of the first group... It makes it an extra effort to parse the text, like when someone makes lots of spelling mistakes. If the person is likely to make language mistakes on top of that it might get downright hard to understand.

I'd say that you "can" do it, in that you won't be the first or last person to do it and plenty of people won't care, but some will.

(to add to the ASCII codes info, if you don't want to write them down or memorize them, know that they follow a specific pattern. Knowing it you can find the correct letter in a few tries, and over time you can end up learning the codes that way.)

Answer (score 3):

It heavily depends on the person you're writing to: I'm a Belgian (Flemish) and I've worked for several years in the French speaking part of the country, where I've done a large effort to speak/write the French language as correct as possible.
If anybody would have written me a French e-mail without any accent, I would have replied "Pardon?", meaning "I don't understand what you are writing.", just to make the point.
Even using an AZERTY keyboard, I did have some issue writing French text (the characters 'Ç' and 'œ' are not present there too), but I've solved this by learning the ASCII codes by heart (199 and 156 in the mentioned cases), and in order to type those characters, I type `ALT+0199` or `ALT+0156`. You might do this for the normal accent characters (just write them on a piece of paper, and put it in front of you, after a short while you'll know them by heart).

For your information:

```
é  ALT+0233
è  ALT+0232
ê  ALT+0234
à  ALT+0224
â  ALT+0226
ù  ALT+0249
û  ALT+0251
```

(You might find all those back using the Windows program "Character Map")

Good luck

Comment: Nice answer. Also writing capital letters with accents is an issue when one works with the AZERTY keyboard. I prefer the QWERTY:-)!. `+shift+A and you have very quickly À without the need to memorize ASCII codes. By the way, following the French Academie even the capital letters should be accentuated: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong

Comment: QWERTY but with International Keyboard activated of course.

Comment: The use of codes is Windows-specific. Unix (and Linux) uses a "Compose" key, much easier to use and works on all keyboard layouts. Regarding "even using AZERTY keyboard", I don't need Compose on Linux, even for capital accented letter: pressing "é" when "Caps Lock" is activated yields "É" where Windows yields "2". Same for ÇÀÉÙÈ. So much easier than learning codes in Windows. There are also shortcuts like `Alt-Gr , C` yielding `Ç` or  `Alt-Gr , o` yielding `œ`, depending on the exact layout. All in all one never has to copy-paste anything when typing French, whatever the physical keyboard.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon  Ok I will try it in Linux. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Note that I have added the following optional feature in [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose) for French users, even if you do not use the main Compose feature: if you press `é` while Caps Lock is on, it will type `É` (instead of `2`). Same for other accented letters.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend using the spell checker as much as possible (it's not hard to add the languages you need and switch between them). It should be available either in your browser or in whatever mailing software you're using.

That should work for most accented words.

Then I think it's important to use accents with *participe passé*, to differentiate between "*mange*" and "*mangé*" for example.

But basically, if a native can deduct the accents the spell checker will, and if not there's an ambiguity and you probably should copy and paste.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the spell checker. Nevertheless, I want to point out that spell checkers are far from being perfect. There is an excellent section in the book MAÎTRISER LES DIFFICULTÉS DU FRANÇAIS POUR RÉUSSIR SES ÉTUDES DE DROIT-ECONOMIE-GESTION (http://www.editions-harmattan.fr/index.asp?navig=catalogue&obj=livre&no=50222) that highlights exactly  this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I was having exchanges in French in environments that did not provide support for accented letters, I was taught to write the accents after the letters.  You can definitely get used to it.

So instead of "ma chère, un hôtel en été ça coûte !", you'd write "ma che`re, un ho^tel en e't'e c,a cou^te !".

Of course using accented characters is preferred.