# Celui-ci / Celui-là / Ceci what's the difference between them?

Tags: choix-de-mot, pronoms, démonstratifs

The meaning of the each are same, but which one is used in what condition?

Comment: Welcome to FSE. Please note the correct spelling: celui-là.

Comment: I know but i don't have that letter on my keyboard.

Comment: I don't know which keyboard you use. The following question could be helpful: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30101/can-i-drop-french-accents-when-writing-computer-text-in-french

Comment: With a QWERTY keyboard I would suggest (valid for the Windows and Ubuntu operational systems alike) the International Keyboard.

You can type very efficiently all the accents (not only for the French language; I use it, for instance, to type German diacritics as well). It suffices to learn some shortcuts and voilà. Everything is thoroughly explained in the following link:

http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/codeint/

For Ubuntu users see

https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu

Comment: For Mac users see: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25643?locale=en_US

Comment: Notice also that the English 1st personal pronoun "I" (unlike its French homologue "je") is written always with a capital letter in whether it starts a sentence or not.

Comment: You should activate the International Keyboard.

Comment: @Lambie The OP has left FSE.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning is very close between ***celui-ci*** and ***celui-là***. In theory, the first one is for things closer than the second one but this nuance is not always respected. We often just favor ***celui-là*** because ***celui-ci*** is formal.

The third one (***ceci***) has a different meaning.

They are close to the English: **this one** (*celui-ci*, formal) , **that one** (*celui-là*) and **this** (*ceci*, formal).

You are missing ***cela*** (formal) and ***ça*** for the English **that**.

***Ça*** can be used for either "this" or "that" so ***C'est quoi, ça ?*** means ***What's this?*** or ***What's that?*** depending on the context.

Note that ***celui*** is masculine singular and must agree with what it refers to, e.g.:

***celui-ci***, ***celle-ci***, ***ceux-ci***, ***celles-ci***

On the other hand, ***ceci***, ***cela*** and ***ça*** are invariable.