# When to use «-là» at the end of a word?

Tags: grammaire

Consider the following (Correct me if I'm wrong in either of the two examples):

> Ce costume-là est en promotion mais pas ce costume-ci.

which translates to - "That suit is on sale but not this suit."

> Ce costume n'est pas à sa taille.

which translates to - "This suit isn't his size."

So when do we use "-là"(or "ci") at the end of nouns?

Comment: You can translate *this thing* to *cette chose-ci* and *that thing* to *cette chose-là*. In English, every time you use *this* or *that*, you have to choose one of them.  But French has a third option, which is say *cette chose* and leave out *ci* or *là*; this is done when the choice of *this* or *that* is either obvious or irrelevant.

Comment: Some British English dialects use the emphatic forms "this here" and "that there". E.g. "I'd like to buy that there suit. This here one doesn't fit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append ***-là*** or more rarely ***-ci*** to a noun to emphasize the fact you are talking about it precisely, as opposite to other ones:

1. *Ce **costume** n'est pas à sa taille.* : This suit doesn't fit him.
2. *Ce **costume-là** n'est pas à sa taille.* : That one (suit) doesn't fit him (but other ones possibly do).

See also: [Celui-ci / Celui-là / Ceci what's the difference between them?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43253/celui-ci-celui-l%C3%A0-ceci-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: So even if we removed là from the second sentence it'll remain grammatically correct?

Comment: Sure, removing "-là" makes it identical to the first one.