# How to type apostrophe {'} with Microsoft French Input?

Tags: usage

Start to learn French recently. With Microsoft French Input, typing <kbd>'</kbd>, next to <kbd>;</kbd> on keyboard, will show <kbd>è</kbd>, but how to type apostrophe?

BTW, I just figured out that the keyboard layout is changed between the different country input. While with English, it is a US keyboard. With French Input, my keyboard is set to Canadian French(Legacy).

With French keyboard, the layout changes a lot from the US keyboard.

Comment: Have you thried to type `'` then `space`?

Comment: It doesn't work here. With Canadian French(Legacy) keyboard, it is "è ". With French keyboard, it is "ù ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a QWERTY keyboard I strongly suggest the **International Keyboard**.

> The US International keyboard layout is a variation of the standard US
> keyboard layout that lets you type all common characters used in
> Catalan, Danish, Dutch, English, Finnish, French, German, Italian,
> Norwegian, Portuguese, Spanish, and Swedish. Some of these characters
> are typed by holding down a special AltChar key, while others are
> typed by pressing a sequence of keys. This keyboard is based on the
> QWERTY keyboard layout that is commonly used in the United States.
>
> To insert the grave accent, acute accent, or circumflex alone, press
> the Spacebar instead of a letter after you press and release the
> accent key (or Shift plus the accent key). To insert the
> umlaut/dieresis alone, press Control plus Shift plus the colon (:)
> key; release, then press the Spacebar. The thing to remember when
> using accent keys with the US International keyboard layout is that
> your computer waits for you to press the next key. Your system needs
> to know whether you want to insert the accent character alone or as an
> accent over a letter. After you press and release the accent key, you
> must press another key before anything is displayed on the screen.

[image]

To answer your question, read the following passage.

[image]

Reference: https://www.csbsju.edu/Documents/MCL/resource/use-int-keyboard.pdf

Everything is thoroughly explained in the following link for Windows users:
http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/codeint/.

For Ubuntu users see: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu.

For Mac users see: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25643?locale=en_US.

See also [Can I drop French accents when writing computer text in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30101/can-i-drop-french-accents-when-writing-computer-text-in-french)
and the answers therein.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @sleepy You are welcome:-)!